# Does numerical dissipation in FE simulations affect system's elastic energy? Does it depend on thickness?

Tags: finite-element-method, solid-mechanics, numerical-methods

I am running a finite-element simulation in Abaqus, for which I also have a theoretical model. To be precise, I am simulating wrinkling in a thin annular sheet, with shell elements. The model makes a prediction for the evolution of the elastic energy with increasing load. I plot this against the `ALLIE` energy variable (`ALLIE = internal energy`, see here: https://abaqus-docs.mit.edu/2017/English/SIMACAEOUTRefMap/simaout-c-exp-totalenergyoutput.htm) that can be obtained from Abaqus, and which is supposed to represent the elastic energy.

Two plots are below. I find that the Abaqus `ALLIE` is always slightly below the expected curve. However, the discrepancy decreases (or vanishes) as the thickness decreases:
For `thickness = 5e-4` (c.f., `system size ~ 1`):

[image: t5e-4],

while for `thickness = 1e-4`:

[image]

Note in particular the marked non-linear behaviour at very small Delta for the thicker sheet, which vanishes for the thinner sheet.

I am trying to figure out why this discrepancy occurs, and why it decreases/vanishes for smaller thickness. I run this simulation in a `Dynamic, Implicit model quasi-static` mode. As explained here (https://abaqus-docs.mit.edu/2017/English/SIMACAEANLRefMap/simaanl-c-dynamic.htm#simaanl-c-dynamic-t-MaterialDamping-sma-topic9), this mode uses a lot of numerical dissipation to make the dynamics quasi-static.

My question, could this numerical dissipation be responsible for decreasing the ALLIE? If not, do you have some ideas as to what could be happening?

Comment: Do you know what causes the nonlinearity on small displacement, or it is anticipated?

Comment: @r13 No, this is also an artefact of using a `Dynamic, implicit` process (maybe the quasi-static part is important). If I use an `Explicit` method instead, I get a different non-linearity (power <1) for small displacement

Comment: is the final displacement in your model and in the simulation the same? The plots that are presented don't explicitly describe which is which and also, at what intervals were the data points collected (neither in the model nor in the simulation). If your model is time dependent, then it might be worth detailing that a bit more.

Comment: Start by modeling a mass on the end of a spring, so you know the exact solution and you can understand what is going on.

Comment: @alephzero That is a good point, yes.

Comment: Hello everyone, I just added more details to my question to make it more precise. Perhaps this will help you give an answer